# Replace regrep for HAproxy 2.x

Tags: haproxy

I need to administrate a server with a previously configured HAproxy v1.8. After updating to v2.4 I noticed the error about regrep not used anymore:

```
[ALERT]    (1574) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:310] : The 'reqrep' directive is not supported anymore since HAProxy 2.1. Use 'http-request replace-path', 'http-request replace-uri' or 'http-request replace-header' instead.
```

I was following some documentation but cannot really be sure I'm using the correct way to replace regrep. The configuration line in haproxy.cfg, in backend section:

```
  reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /amc[/]?(.*)  \1\ //\2
```

What is the correct way to update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that you want to replace the path.
You can try the following, untested.

```
http-request replace-path /amc[/]?(.*) /\1
```

More examples can be found in the doc [http-request replace-path](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20replace-path)

Comment: @Alexander, hi, can you give me a clue on my question? If I use haproxy on single web server and create multiple nodes (like kubenetes), then can be better than only one node? or as long as one server, the same availibility?

Comment: Please open a new question and explain a little bit more what you try todo.